# How to get parent module atts value at it's child module in divi builder?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created custom divi builder module with its child module. now i need parent atts value at its child module, but i cant find way to solve this problem.
Here is my custom module class

Parent module class:

```
class Wb_Custom_Module_Revision extends ET_Builder_Module {

function init () {
    $this->name = __( 'Wb Revision Log', 'wb' );
    $this->slug = 'et_pb_wb_revision';
    $this->fb_support      = true;
    $this->child_slug      = 'et_pb_wb_revision_child';
    $this->child_item_text = esc_html__( 'Revision Item', 'et_builder' );
    $this->whitelisted_fields = array('vertical_divider_line');
    $this->fields_defaults = array(
        'title' => array( 'Revision Log', 'add_default_setting' ),
    );
    $this->main_css_element = '%%order_class%%';
}
function get_fields () {
    $fields = array(
        'vertical_divider_line' => array(
            'label' => __( 'Horizontal line', 'wb' ),
            'type' => 'text',
            'description' => __( 'Leave empty to not display', 'wb' ),
        ),
    );
    return $fields;
}
function shortcode_callback ( $atts, $content = null, $function_name ) {

   //my shortcode function 
    return ;
}
}
new Wb_Custom_Module_Revision;
```

Child module class:

```
class Wb_Custom_Module_Revision_Item extends ET_Builder_Module {

function init() {
    $this->name             = esc_html__( 'Revision Item', 'et_builder' );
    $this->slug             = 'et_pb_wb_revision_child';
    $this->fb_support       = true;
    $this->type             = 'child';
    $this->child_title_var  = 'content_new';

function shortcode_callback( $atts, $content = null, $function_name ) {
    //i need here it's parent "vertical_divider_line" field value. 

    return $output;
}
}
new Wb_Custom_Module_Revision_Item;
```

I need Parent module field value in its child module shortcode_callback function.
please help me to solve this.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the parent module by calling this class method:

`$parent_module = self::get_parent_modules('page')['et_pb_wb_revision'];`

and then you can get the desired field value:

`$parent_module->shortcode_atts['vertical_divider_line'];`

Hope it helps!

Comment: self::get_parent_modules('page')['et_pb_section'] works for me!

Comment: What about jsx file? how to do same in jsx files?